# can't get a result of google-calendar-api request in php (only in terminal)

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm having some trouble using google calendar api,
here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php
there is a php file to execute in order to get the incomming events in a calendar (the file name is quickstart.php).

When I execute it in my windows terminal with the command
'$php quickstart.php' it runs perfectly, there is a result displayed in the terminal.

I wanted to get the result in php so I can work with it or at least display it on a web page but as soon as I launch the page with my navigator, I get the error "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: This application must be run on the command line." Which is created at the beginning of quickstart.php.. How can I make it work? get the result in a variable and work with it?

thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 1):

That sample was intended to be run as an installed application its not meant to be run on the web.  The code and the client you will use are different.  The actual calls the the api are the same.

The first thing you need to do is go to the developer console and create browser credentials.

### [oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php)

```
   require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';
    // Start a session to persist credentials.
    session_start();
    // Handle authorization flow from the server.
    if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client = buildClient();
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    } else {
        $client = buildClient();
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
        // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
        //Redirect back to main script
        $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
```

### [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();
    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}
/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}
/**
 * Builds the redirect uri.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#choosingredirecturi
 * Hostname and current server path are needed to redirect to oauth2callback.php
 * @return A redirect uri.
 */
function getRedirectUri(){
    //Building Redirect URI
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    //returns the current URL
    if(strrpos($url, '?') > 0)
        $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '?') );  // Removing any parameters.
    $folder = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') );   // Removeing current file.
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $folder. '/oauth2callback.php';
}
/**
 * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
 * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
 *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {

        $client = buildClient();

        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }

        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 

            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The reset of the code you need can be found on my sample project [Calendar v3](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3)

I also have a tutorila here but i think the sample code above is newer [Google Calendar OAuth2 – PHP](https://www.daimto.com/accessing-google-calendar-with-php-oauth2/)

Comment: What do you mean by "create browser credentials"? is it here "https://console.developers.google.com" in credentials?